# Configuring internet to run off wifi instead of wired connection

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I am running a small network between 2 computers at my home. I have a Server and a Downloading computer. For the server and Downloading computer to connect to the internet I use WiFi for both of them. I also have a cross-over cable going between the 2 computers. I have setup the wired connections of both computers to be on the same network but the internet seems to try and use the wired connection instead of wireless.

I was wondering if there is a way to have everything that used the internet look at the WiFi network instead of the wired network.

Comment: I've only ever done this using a static ip address for each connection. In NM edit each of your connections. Choose the appropriate tab (IPv4 settings or IPv6 settings, or both if you use both of them), click on the 'Routes' button. In the next dialog enter the same static ip address, netmask and gateway as defined for this connection then set the metric. I believe a lower number gives higher priority to a connection, so if you want wifi to have priority give it a metric of say 10, and a metric of 20 to your ethernet connection. Note: I haven't done this with a crossover cable before so YMMV

Answer (score 0):

On the Ethernet connection there should be no default route. With NetworkNanager you configure that via `nmcli connection modify $NAME ipv4.never-default yes` and re-activate the connection for the change to take effect (that is `nmcli connection $NAME up`).

You can also use one of the GUIs, for example in nm-connection-editor, go to the IPv4 tab, then "Routes", then "use this connection only for local stuff " (or something like that).